# Assign a record to a user in another business unit

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Can I assign a record to a user in another business unit in Dynamics CRM?

Because when I try to do it, I got an odd error message.

Comment: This is purely based on how your system is implemented like security role privileges. btw, Whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need `Organization` level (full green circle) `Assign` privilege to do so